# Keras LSTM Error

Tags: python, macos, clang, keras, lstm

I get the following error when I try to run the LSTM text generator example from keras examples.

Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', DotModulo(A, s, m, A2, s2, m2), '\n', "Compilation failed (return status=1): clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-sse4a'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-tbm'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-fma4'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-prfchw'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-rdseed'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-sha'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+cx16'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+xsave'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+bmi2'. clang: error: language not recognized: 'savec'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+fsgsbase'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+avx'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+rtm'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+popcnt'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+fma'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+bmi'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+aes'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+rdrnd'. clang: error: language not recognized: 'saves'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse4.1'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse4.2'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+avx2'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+lzcnt'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+pclmul'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+f16c'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+ssse3'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+mmx'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+cmov'. clang: error: language not recognized: 'op'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+movbe'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+hle'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+xsaveopt'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse2'. clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse3'. ", '[DotModulo(A, s, m, A2, s2, m2)]')

I haven't made any changes to the code except pass in my own data to it. Here's my code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
import numpy as np
import random
import sys

text = texts[0]
print('corpus length:', len(text))

chars = set(text)
print('total chars:', len(chars))
char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

# cut the text in semi-redundant sequences of maxlen characters
maxlen = 40
step = 3
sentences = []
next_chars = []
for i in range(0, len(text) - maxlen, step):
    sentences.append(text[i: i + maxlen])
    next_chars.append(text[i + maxlen])
print('nb sequences:', len(sentences))

print('Vectorization...')
X = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
        X[i, t, char_indices[char]] = 1
    y[i, char_indices[next_chars[i]]] = 1


# build the model: 2 stacked LSTM
print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(maxlen,     len(chars))))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(len(chars)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')


def sample(a, temperature=1.0):
    # helper function to sample an index from a probability array
    a = np.log(a) / temperature
    a = np.exp(a) / np.sum(np.exp(a))
    return np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1, a, 1))

# train the model, output generated text after each iteration
for iteration in range(1, 60):
    print()
    print('-' * 50)
    print('Iteration', iteration)
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=1)

    start_index = random.randint(0, len(text) - maxlen - 1)

    for diversity in [0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.2]:
        print()
        print('----- diversity:', diversity)

        generated = ''
        sentence = text[start_index: start_index + maxlen]
        generated += sentence
        print('----- Generating with seed: "' + sentence + '"')
        sys.stdout.write(generated)

        for i in range(400):
            x = np.zeros((1, maxlen, len(chars)))
            for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
                x[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1.

            preds = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0]
            next_index = sample(preds, diversity)
            next_char = indices_char[next_index]

            generated += next_char
            sentence = sentence[1:] + next_char

            sys.stdout.write(next_char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        print()
```

Please help me.

Comment: Your code seems correct. More like clang compiler related error. Maybe try it on a machine with gcc

Comment: Have any neural network model compiled ever on your Keras installation?

Comment: It used to work. It suddenly stopped working with this LSTM. Now none of my Theano code works. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling theano and it hasn't helped. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a clang related error. After Apple updated the xCode tools my clang became incompatible with Nvidia's Cuda drivers. Updating the drivers fixed the problem. If a new update isn't available one needs to either wait for one or rollback their xCode tools.